# Invalid arguments in Command

Tags: batch-file

Thanks for looking into my question.

I have a batch command to copy the files to remote server and if I run this command from command prompt it ran well.

```
echo D|xcopy /E /Y ..\Media \\%Win_Machine%\C$\temp\%APP_VERSION%\Media
```

Whereas if I run the same command through batch file, it says "Invalid number of parameters".

Please help me if I am missing anything here.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the `echo D`. Just add a backslash at the end of the destination directory to indicate that it's a new directory and not a file: `xcopy /E /Y ..\Media "\\%Win_Machine%\C$\temp\%APP_VERSION%\Media\"`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo D|xcopy /E /Y ..\Media "\\%Win_Machine%\C$\temp\%APP_VERSION%\Media"
```

Invalid number of parameters would indicate that `xcopy` sees three or more parameters. Since the first two arguments are switches, then it would seem that the final argument is being interpreted as two or more parameters - which would mean that the values of the user-variables would contain separators. Quoting the arguments tells `cmd` to interpret the string between the quotes as a single entity.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved. Forgot to post the answer. I see extra spaces being posted %APP_VERSION%. It is working fine now.
anyway, Thanks Magoo for valuable inputs.